# Simple function with a couple of properties

Tags: functions, special-functions

Please supply any simple function $f(x | p)$ which the following properties:

1. $f(0 | p) = 0$ and $f(1 | p)=0$
2. $f'(0 | p) = 0$ and $f'(1 | p)=0$
3. $f(x | p)>0$ for $0<x<1$
4. For $0<x<1$ there is one maxima at $p$: $f'(p | p)=0$ (for $0<p<1$)
5. $f(x | p)$ is continuous and differentiable for the interval $[0,1]$

It would look like a skewed bell shape within the interval $[0,1]$, for which the place of the peak is given by $p$.

**Edit**: A simple function such as $f(x) = x^2 (1-x)^2$ satisfies all requirements but 4. How would I modify it such that it's maxima is at $p$ instead of $0.5$?

If you could help me, then that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Read about bump functions at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function. The function $\Psi$ in the section "Examples" is a classic one, and you can find its graph there as well. It should be easy enough to modify this function by shifting and scaling to meet your requirements.

Bear in mind that there are infinitely many examples of the sort of function you describe. But I think most mathematicians would probably come up some variant of this one.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to modify a function such that its maximum is at a given spot $p$, while the places $x_\min$ and $x_\max$ stay at the same place ($0$ and $1$).

Comment: You can make the maximum of any function $f$ anything you want by looking at $cf$, $c$ some positive constant. Then $\max(cf(x)) = c\max(f(x))$, and this won't change that $cf(0)=cf(1)=c\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: Also, if $f$ achieves a maximum at $p_0$ you can make it achieve its maximum at $p$ by looking at $g(x) = f(x-p+p_0)$, Then $g(p) = f(p_0)$, and $g$ and $f$ have the same maximum so $p$ is the maximizer for $g$.

Comment: If I just shift a function along the $x$-axis, then the function wouldn't give $f(0|p)=0$ and $f(1|p)=0$ anymore! Instead these properties will hold at $x=0-p$ and $x=1-p$ respectively.

Comment: You can also scale the endpoints of a function by putting a constant in the argument: $f(ax)$ will scale the endpoints of your function to wherever you need them to be.

Comment: Your solutions don't cause the function to be skewed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13436/discussion-between-angelorf-and-kigen)

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f(x)=x^2 (1-x)^2$ we can introduce skewness by mapping the input via a non-linear function $x = g(y)$ for which $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. For example, let's take the function $g(y) = y^a$. For $a>1$ we'll see that $f(g(y))$ will be skewed to the left, and it will be skewed to the right for $0<a<1$.

Note that $f'(y) = 0 $ for $ a = - \frac{\log 2}{\log x} $ and so the function $h(x) = (x^{- \ln 2/\ln p})^2*(1-x^{- \ln 2/\ln p})^2 $ meets all the requirements.